# Recording audio samples on iOS using AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, avfoundation, recording

Choosing the audio format in which AVFoundation audio samples are captured.

I am familiar with processing of video frames coming from the iPhone camera. There, the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`'s [`videoSettings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009544) property could be used to specify the format in which the video frames should be receievd.

For audio, the similar class [AVCaptureAudioDataOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureAudioDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009547) does not have such a property.

However, the `AVAudioSettings.h` file clearly shows that there exist several audio formats.

- How can I choose a format for audio data? I'm basically interested in raw PCM samples with a certain specific bit rate.

Answer (score -3):

You can try [OpenAL](https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone). Here is the [Documentation](http://kstenerud.github.com/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/).  Best regards ;)